# creating maven project error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, struts2

```
mvn archetype:generate -B              
  -DgroupId=com.my-company.my-project           
     -DartifactId=my-project-domain           
     -DpackageName=com.company.project.domain    
            -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes    
            -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-struts    
       -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo    
            -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0
```

I typed the above command to create my maven-hibernate project. After this i went into my project folder and typed `mvn eclipse:eclipse` followed by `mvn clean install`

thereafter, i in the eclipse IDE, i clicked `import --> existing projects in to workspace` but i couldn't open this because the pom.xml wasn't there.

Note: When i typed `mvn clean install` i got the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compil
e (default) on project my-project-domain: The artifact org.springframework:sprin
g-aspects referenced in aspectj plugin as an aspect library, is not found the pr
 oject dependencies -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
 ch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

**EDIT**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
    3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-project-domain: Compilation failure
      [ERROR] \Users\Administrator\Documents\MYPROJECTS\my-project-domain\src\main
     \java\com\my-company\my-project\App.java:[1,14] ';' expected
     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Even though it says there's a missing `;` sign, when i checked the `App.java` file i didn't find any syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the hyphen in your package path.

Answer (score 5):

> The artifact `org.springframework:spring-aspects` referenced in aspectj
>   plugin as an aspect library, is not found the project dependencies

you need to add the dependency for this plugin artifact

Comment: I did this; but i still get the error; `<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.9</version>
                    </dependency>`

Comment: that isn't the correct dependency, the dependency artifact is `org.springframework:spring-aspects` as I list in my answer

Comment: I have edited my question above, could you please look into it